# Scala: branching statement optimisation using callback function degrading performance

Tags: performance, scala

It is common in C/C++ programming to use function pointers to optimize branching in the main data path. So I wrote a test program to find out if similar performance savings can be gotten in Scala using functional programming techniques. The usecase is that of a function which is invoked millions of times and has a branching statement based on a global flag. The code using if() statement -

```
val b = true
def test() = {
  if(b) // do something
  else  // do something else
}
for(i <- 0 to 100000) test()
```

And trying to get rid of the if() I did this -

```
def onTrue() = { // do something }
def onFalse() = { // do something else }
lazy val callback: () => Unit = if(b) onTrue else onFalse
def test() = callback()
for(i <- 0 to 100000) test()
```

I did a comparison of both these programs by running them for large counters (in the for loop) and running them many times and using the System.nanoTime() differential to measure the time taken.

And my tests seem to suggest that the callback method is actually SLOWER than using if() in the loop. The reason for this could be that a function call requires the params and returns to be pushed on the stack and a new stack frame created etc. Given this finding wanted to know -

1. Is there a functional way one could code which will better the performance of using the if() in the loop with Scala?
2. @inline works with compiler. Is there a runtime equivalent to avoid the stack activities? (similar to tail call optimization)
3. Could my test or results be inaccurate/erroneous in some way?

Comment: I don't know Scala well enough to answer your question, but do you have any reference/examples to support your statement "It is common in C/C++ programming to use function pointers to optimize branching in the main data path"?

Comment: As written your callback version results in an extra object allocation for every loop. The short answer is don't do this—any decent JVM will do a better job of optimizing the conditional than you could.

Comment: @GabrielSouthern you are correct to point a flaw in my assertion. even C/C++ function pointers wont better the performance for a simple if() like above. only more complicated if() with multiple conditions or nested if() will have a material impact, if at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3) It's very easy to get your methodology wrong when testing this way.  Use something like JMH if you want quasi-trustable microbenchmarks!

2) The JVM does inlining at runtime.

1) You aren't measuring a difference in whether something is "functional".  You're measuring the difference between using a lazy val and not.  If you don't have the lazy val in there, the JVM will probably be able to optimize your code (depending on what "do something" is).

If you remove the lazy val, the second one optimizes to the same speed in my hands.  (It has an extra mandatory check for every access that it isn't being initialized in a multi-threaded context.)